# Leaflet + Angular is it possible to draw semicircles?

Tags: angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, ngx-leaflet

In my angular application, I use maps through the [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) library and [openstreet maps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/-15.13/-53.19). And now we need to draw semicircles.
I know there is a [Leaflet-semicircle](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle) extension, but I have already installed this dependency via Angular, but I cannot use the objects to draw a semi circle.
Is there any way to use the leaflet-semicircle extension in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the correct way to draw semicircles. The problem was that in addition to installing the Leaflet-semicircle extension via npm I needed to import the javascript file properly.

Just follow the steps:

```
npm i leaflet --save  
npm install --save leaflet-semicircle
```

In angular.json file add the libraries as follows:

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
      "./node_modules/leaflet-semicircle/semicircle.js"
  ]
```

And finaly, the problem was here:

```
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-semicircle';

//Right way to import and extend all extensions importeds previously
declare let L;

//Doesn't works */
//import * as L from 'leaflet';
```